# Radix Sort in Descending Order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, radix

I can sort an array in ascending order, but I don't know how to sort it in descending order.

```
void radixSort(int *a, int arraySize)
{

    int i, bucket[arraySize];

    int maxVal = 0;

    int digitPosition =1;

    for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > maxVal)
        maxVal = a[i];
    }

    int pass = 1; 

    while(maxVal/digitPosition > 0) 
    {

        int digitCount[10] = {0};

        for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            digitCount[a[i]/digitPosition%10]++;

        for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            digitCount[i] += digitCount[i-1];

        for(i = arraySize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            bucket[--digitCount[a[i]/digitPosition%10]] = a[i];


        for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            a[i] = bucket[i];

        digitPosition *= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: `bucket[arraySize]` uses VLA extension and is not valid C++.

Comment: Why not use 9's complement math? Subtract each digit from 9: 9 - {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}, which would change the sort to descending.

Answer (score 0):

```
void radixSort(int *a, int arraySize){
    vector<int> mybucket[10];
    int i,j,maxVal = 0,digitPosition=1;
    for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
        if(a[i] > maxVal)
            maxVal = a[i];
    }
    int p =1;
    char str[20];
    sprintf( str,"%d",maxVal);
    while( p <= strlen(str) ){
        for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            mybucket[(a[i]/digitPosition)%10].push_back(a[i]);
        int k = 0;
        for( i = 9;i>=0;i--){
            for(j=0;j<mybucket[i].size();j++){
                a[k++] = mybucket[i][j];
            }
            mybucket[i].clear();
        }
        digitPosition *= 10;
        p+=1;
    }
}
```

Edit1:

Here, we have 10 mybuckets vector each of them will hold input number(s) based on their Kth least significant digit in decimal. Where k will be vary from 1 to N(max number of digits in the given input).

```
e.g.
for k =  2
and a = [1,23,45,127,345,1]
mybucket[0] = [1,1]
mybucket[2] = [23,127]
mybucket[4] = [45,345]
```

What above code does is it extracts Kth least significant digit from the input and put's into the respective bucket in each iteration. After processing all numbers we take out these numbers from mybuckets and put back into the input array and start the process with (K+1)th least significant digit. We keep on doing this until there is no more least significant digit left in the given input numbers.

**Note: This process will run for maximum number of digits time in the given input number(s)**

```
e.g. a = [83,86,77,15,93,35,86,92,49,21,62,27,90,59,63,26,40,26,72,36,93]
Iteration1
Bucket9[49,59,]
Bucket8[]
Bucket7[77,27,]
Bucket6[86,86,26,26,36,]
Bucket5[15,35,]
Bucket4[]
Bucket3[83,93,63,]
Bucket2[92,62,72,]
Bucket1[21,]
Bucket0[90,40,]

Iteration2
Bucket9[93,92,90,]
Bucket8[86,86,83,]
Bucket7[77,72,]
Bucket6[63,62,]
Bucket5[59,]
Bucket4[49,40,]
Bucket3[36,35,]
Bucket2[27,26,26,21,]
Bucket1[15,]
Bucket0[]
O/P:
[93,92,90,86,86,83,77,72,63,62,59,49,40,36,35,27,26,26,21,15]
```

As we have the maximum number of digits is 2 so this run for 2 iterations.

Check [Radix sort in descending order](http://ideone.com/FuATOI) for working code.

Edit2/3:
You can use any data structure only thing we have to care is that insertion in the respective bucket and retrieval from the bucket. Here we need to follow a strict rule for insertion and deletion in the bucket otherwise, you may get o/p in random order.

```
Algorithm: (Assuming only positive number(s) is/are as given input)
k <- 1
maxVal <- 0
foreach number from inputs:
  maxVal = max( number ,  maxVal )

/*Collection of bucket, which will hold all 
 the numbers whose kth significant digit is d[0-9].*/
buckets[ ] 
1. foreach number from inputs:
     d <- k_th_least_significant( number,  k )
     buckets[ d ] .insert ( number )
2.  count <- 1
    for indx = maximum bucket index to lowest bucket index:
       for j = 1 to j <= buckets[ indx ].size():
           inputs[ count ] = buckets[ indx ][ j ]
           count <- count + 1
3. k <- k + 1
4. if number_of_digit( maxVal ) <= k :
    go to step 1
5. Print inputs
```

Others way to implement this.

1. Linked List 
     a) 2 Dimensional linked list 
     b) Array of 1 Dimensional linked list
2. Array 
     a) Array of dynamic size 1-D array
     b) 2-D dynamic array here (we have to deal with re-sizing of array)
    c) Use maxm size array ( 1-D or 2-D) 
     d) array from standard library
3. map from STL or implement your own Use [0-9] as key and value as
    a ) linked list 
    b ) vector or array pointer ( you may have to deal with insertion )
4. Hashing using bucket concept ( where key will be integer[0-9] and you have to map multiple values to same hash key )
5. Queue ( 2-d Queue or 1-D Queue )

e.t.c.

Comment: Could you add in some context, such as how the code works?

Comment: @UniformsForSale sure.

Comment: Are there any ways of implementing it without using the vector library, like what signs should be changed?

Comment: Yes. i will add these details.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)